# Postgres another issue with "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables in my Postgres database.

```
vehicles
- veh_id PK
- veh_number


positions
- position_id PK
- vehicle_id FK
- time
- latitude
- longitude
.... few more fields
```

I have multiple entries in Position table for every Vehicle. I would like to get all vehicle positions but the newest ones (where time field is latest). I tried query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM positions
GROUP BY vehicle_id
ORDER BY time DESC
```

But there's an error:

```
column "positions.position_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I tried to change it to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM positions
GROUP BY vehicle_id, position_id
ORDER BY time DESC
```

but then it doesn't group entries.

I tried to found similiar problems e.g.:

[PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161696/postgresql-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

or

[GroupingError: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942477/groupingerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an)

but I didn't really helped with my problem.

Could you help me fix my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is simple if you have columns on the `SELECT` those should be also on the `GROUP` section unless they are wrapped with aggregated function

Also dont use `*` use the column names

```
  SELECT col1, col2, MAX(col3), COUNT(col4), AVG(col5) -- aggregated columns 
                                                       -- dont go in GROUP BY
  FROM yourTable  
  GROUP BY  col1, col2   -- all not aggregated field
```

Now regarding your query, looks like you want

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT * ,
            row_number() over (partition by vehicle_id order by time desc) rn
     FROM positions
     ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: thank you, your query is working perfectly and now I understand how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this group by clause
**GROUP BY  position_id,vehicle_id**
primary key then FK